Passing a value returned from a function into a d3.filter
I am trying to pass a value from a function that locates a name from a dropdown list in my html and have it as the argument in my d3.filter.
The function works fine, but I cannot seem to figure out how to insert the returned value as the filter condition within my d3 call.
let inputvalue = getApplicatorNames();
let quotedvalue = `"${inputvalue}"`;

d3.json(PesticideDBraw).then(data => {
  const FilteredRecords = data.filter(App => App.Applicator.some(name => name.includes(quotedvalue)));

function getApplicatorNames() {
  let appSelect = document.getElementById("NameData");
  let optsSelect = appSelect.options.length;
  let appIndex = appSelect.selectedIndex;
  let ApplicatorName = appSelect.options[appSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(ApplicatorName);
  return ApplicatorName;
}


Does anyone see what I cannot see?
Refer to the code above.  I've tried reassigning the element to another variable.  Using d3.select to catch the returned value from the html tag.  Each time I keep getting type errors and empty arrays called.
//Example of JSON DATA


{
        "Application Number": "46",
        "Requested By": "STEVE USSERY",
        "Date": "3/28/2000",
        "Start Time": "10:15 AM",
        "Finish Time": "12:15 PM",
        "Applicator": [
            "NICHOLAS RINGER"
        ],
        "Licensed Applicator": "STEVE USSERY",
        "Size of Area": "6000",
        "Chemical": {
            "TankMix1": "FALSE",
            "TankMix2": "FALSE",
            "Completed": "TRUE",
            "Total Solution": "45",
            "UoM": "GAL",
            "Method": "Hydraulic",
            "Location": "109",
            "Chemical (1)": "Bonzi",
            "Target/Pest (1)": [
                "PGR"
            ],
            "Rate (1)": "0.5 oz/gal",
            "Total Product (1)": "22.5",
            "Chemical (2)": "",
            "Target/Pest (2)": [
                ""
            ],
            "Rate (2)": "",
            "Total Product (2)": "",
            "Chemical (3)": "",
            "Target/Pest (3)": [
                ""
            ],
            "Rate (3)": "",
            "Total Product (3)": ""
        },
        "Completed": "TRUE"
    },
    {
        "Application Number": "48",
        "Requested By": "DEBORAH BURTON",
        "Date": "3/28/2000",
        "Start Time": "2:30 PM",
        "Finish Time": "3:45 PM",
        "Applicator": [
            "PABLO ALVAREZ-ALVARADO",
            " NICHOLAS RINGER"
        ],
        "Licensed Applicator": "DEBORAH BURTON",
        "Size of Area": "500",
        "Chemical": {
            "TankMix1": "FALSE",
            "TankMix2": "FALSE",
            "Completed": "TRUE",
            "Total Solution": "3",
            "UoM": "GAL",
            "Method": "Drench",
            "Location": "cold frame c-18",
            "Chemical (1)": "M-Pede",
            "Target/Pest (1)": [
                "Aphids"
            ],
            "Rate (1)": "1gallon to 100galllons",
            "Total Product (1)": "0.360000014",
            "Chemical (2)": "",
            "Target/Pest (2)": [
                ""
            ],
            "Rate (2)": "",
            "Total Product (2)": "",
            "Chemical (3)": "",
            "Target/Pest (3)": [
                ""
            ],
            "Rate (3)": "",
            "Total Product (3)": ""
        },
        "Completed": "TRUE"
    },




You don't show your data but your .filter call seems strange.  Your data is an array of objects, with a property of Applicator which is an array of objects, with a property of name which is an array of strings that have literal " in them?

Mark,  You are absolutely correct on all accounts.  The data was extracted and transformed from a MS Access database.  The company I work for doesn't have any other SQL based programs, so I have to work with what I have, and integrating Access schemas into js has been just as challenging.
I've posted a snip of the JSON data if that helps you understand more.  The goal is to prepare a dashboard that will tell the user how many records a specific Applicator that was selected from the drop down list has performed.

I think your problem is in this let quotedvalue = \"${inputvalue}"`;.   Your Applicatorarray is just an array of strings, there are no literal quotes.   Your code would match to"Applicator": [""NICHOLAS RINGER""]and not"Applicator": ["NICHOLAS RINGER"]`.

I would have originally agreed, but the filter call rejects the  inputvalue just the same.
If I use the inputvalue as the condition in my d3.filter it breaks the select dropdown in the html and I receive a TyperError - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') at getApplicatorNames.
Maybe the HTML isn't loading the data when I call the getApplicatorNames()

You might need to post more code to debug further.  I tried what you have posted and doing what I suggested does indeed work.   I'm curious how handle the JSON download and selection from the dropdown.  Does changing the dropdown selection re-download and parse the file?

@Mark.
Thanks for your help earlier.  I was able to solve the problem.  The async was out of order and my earlier thought was right and the html was loading the data after I called the function.  But it is now solved.  Thanks again!
